# How to remove encryption from a directory encrypted with fscrypt?

Tags: linux-mint, encryption

I applied encryption with fscrypt on my home folder on Linux Mint. But now I decided to remove encryption and try something else. I read through the readme of the project, but I couldn't really find exact instructions, how to remove encryption.
I have an assumption it could be done maybe by making a backup and deleting the home folder itself and with the `fscrypt metadata` command. But I'm not sure about it.
Does anyone know the exact steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can't remove encryption. So to achieve that :

1. Copy home files elsewhere (note that having good backups is considered a good practice)
2. Remove /home/theuser directory
3. Create a new /home/theuser directory and apply owner-group permissions
4. Copy files back home

enjoy